# Role Manager in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm creating a page to manage the roles and users.

```
public class UserHelper
{
    private readonly IdentityContext _context = new IdentityContext();
    public List<IdentityRole> GetRoles()
    {
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_context);
        var roleMngr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);//ERROR//

        var roles = roleMngr.Roles.ToList();
        return roles;
    }
```

And also here my IdentityContext class:

```
 public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
 {
    public IdentityContext()
    {
    }

    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Finally startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddTransient<ICacheHelper, CacheHelper>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I didn't understand what cause to the problem occured in the RoleManager.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Ali, why not using constructor dependency injection the RoleManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did seems to be used in asp.net. In asp.net core, you just use constructor dependency injection like below:

```
public class UserHelper
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    public UserHelper(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }
    public List<IdentityRole> GetRoles()
    {
        var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
        return roles;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You could DI `RoleManager` in razor view like below:

```
@inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager
@{
    var jsonRollerArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(new UserHelper(_roleManager).GetRoles()));
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for replying. I just want to ask something. I call this GetRoles() method in Index.cshtml. I don't know how to pass parameter rolemanager. Can you help with that ?              var jsonRollerArray = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(new ImOnTech.Hukuk.Web.Helpers.UserHelper().GetRoles()))';  @Rena

Comment: Hi @Ali, you could use `@inject` to inject the service. Check my updated answer.